# Explanation of accurate measurements css 3d cube

Tags: css, 3d, transform

I have created a cube based on this example.
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transforms/#cubecarousel

What I need to understand is how can I get an exact measure (for example of 200px) of the facing side?

Usually you define the cube's faces and then you apply the transformation at half of the object (50%) so the object gets shifted forward.
How would I push it back so the facing side matches 200px?

Thank you

Comment: see if [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect) helps. It takes transforms into account when giving you the dimensions, position, etc.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K99GS/

Answer (score 0):

You should post your current code.

Anyway, I guess that your current images are 200px ?

Then taking into account that (from your link):

> A 3D image slider
>   Note that because of the way a cube works, the image
>   is moved out towards the screen, and is bigger than it should be. You
>   should move it back by half the width of an image to make sure it is
>   normal size.

If you translate your cube 100px (half the width) backwards, your images will be exactly 200px.

If your images are not 200px, definitely post your code

Comment: Ok, here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/K99GS/

I tried pushing it backwards, but it changes the pivot so it rotates from the wrong origin...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the fiddle: jsfiddle.net/K99GS I tried pushing it backwards, but it changes the pivot so it rotates from the wrong origin...

Answer (score 0):

Ok after trying for one day... I found out my solution was a DUD.
Here is the exact cube (216px) and the code.
How do I push it back????????
Here is the relevant css code:

```
#controls, #transparency {
  text-align:center;
}
#controls span {
  padding-right:2em;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#cubeCarousel {
-webkit-perspective: 800;
-moz-perspective: 800px;
-ms-perspective: 800;
perspective: 800;

-webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
-moz-perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
-ms-perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
perspective-origin: 50% 100px;

margin:100px auto 20px auto;
width:216px;
height:216px;
}

#cubeCarousel #cubeSpinner {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 216px;
  width: 216px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 108px 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 108px 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 108px 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 108px 0;

  -webkit-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;

 }

#cubeCarousel #Ycube,#cubeCarousel #Zcube {
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#cubeCarousel .face {
position: absolute;
height: 216px;
width: 216px;
padding: 0px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}


#cubeSpinner .one {
-webkit-transform: translateZ(108px);
-moz-transform: translateZ(108px);
-ms-transform: translateZ(108px);
transform: translateZ(108px);
}

#cubeSpinner .two {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(108px);
-moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(108px);
-ms-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(108px);
transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(108px);
}

#cubeSpinner .three {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(108px);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(108px);
-ms-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(108px);
transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(108px);
}

#cubeSpinner .four {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(108px);
-moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(108px);
-ms-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(108px);
transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(108px);
}
```

See it in action -> 
 http://jsfiddle.net/K99GS/5/